# How to filter custom taxonomy categories on archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query

I'm trying to modify my archive.php where I can select the categories and filter their records.

I can display the categories, detect if is a taxonomy page, but by selecting them, they are not filtering. what am I doing wrong?

When I select a category, it is showing all records, but without filtering.

**archive.php**

```
<?php }elseif(is_tax('downloads-category')){ ?>
<section id="conteudo">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Category Name</h1>
            <?php if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')){ yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>'); }?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-master">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row more-gutter">
                <aside class="col-sm-3">

                </aside>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <?php 
                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                        $infoDownload = array(
                            'post_type' => 'downloads', 
                            'taxonomy'=>'downloads-category',
                            'paged' => $paged
                        );
                        $resultadoDownload = new WP_Query($infoDownload); 
                        if ($resultadoDownload->have_posts()) :
                        while ($resultadoDownload->have_posts()) : $resultadoDownload->the_post();
                            $postThumb = (has_post_thumbnail()) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url() : get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/img/layout/sem-imagem.jpg";
                            $postThumb = "<img src=\"".$postThumb."\" class=\"img-fluid\">";
                        ?>
                        <div class="row lista-download">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <?php echo $postThumb; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php 
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        endwhile;
                        wpbs_pagination();
                        endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**functions.php**

```
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type('downloads',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Downloads'),
                'featured_image' => __('Imagem Capa'),
                'singular_name' => __('Download'),
            ),
            'taxonomies'  => array('downloads-category'),
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'custom-fields',
                'thumbnail'
            ),
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-category',
            'with_front' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'downloads'),
        )
    );
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Categorias', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Categoria', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' =>  __('Procurar categoria'),
        'all_items' => __('Todos'),
        'edit_item' => __('Editar categoria'), 
        'update_item' => __('Editar categoria'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar categoria'),
        'new_item_name' => __('Nova categoria')
    );    
    register_taxonomy('downloads-category',array('downloads'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'categoria-de-downloads', 'with_front' => false),
    ));   
}
add_action('init', 'create_posttype');
```

Oh, and when i use tax_query, doesnt show anything...

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$infoDownload = array(
    'post_type' => 'downloads',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'=>'downloads-category',
            'field'    => 'slug'
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
$resultadoDownload = new WP_Query($infoDownload); 
if ($resultadoDownload->have_posts()) :
```

Comment: Your `tax_query` is missing the `terms` parameter - see [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). Without valid term IDs or slugs, the `tax_query` won't work. And the `'taxonomy'=>'downloads-category'` in your `archive.php`, "they are not filtering" because your query *args* constructs `WP_Query` to query for *all* `downloads` CPT posts regardless their categories (in the `downloads-category` taxonomy).

Comment: Would clear up two things: First: **What do you mean by "Category"?** For example, do you mean a conventional WordPress category or maybe you mean your custom taxonomy that you refer to as 'Categorias/Categoria' (which translates as '_Category_'). Second: **What do you mean by "filtering"?** You say "they are not filtering", "it is showing all records, but without filtering". For example, do you mean that all the posts are being displayed but you only want to see the posts for the term that you clicked?

Comment: You've not responded to my comments nor have you awarded the bounty. My answer addressed your question, why do you not award the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recap: You created a custom post type = "*downloads*" and a custom taxonomy = "*downloads_category*" with a rewrite to "categoria-de-downloads"

**First**: The "**is_tax**" at the head of your archive.php is failing because the name of your custom taxonomy should be "**downloads_category**"; it must be spelt with an **underline** rather than a hyphen ([Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Parameters)).
You also need to change this in:

1. "**register_taxonomy**": the name of your custom taxonomy,
2. "**register_post_type**": the 'taxonomies' line,
3. "**tax_query**": the 'taxonomy' line.

**Second**: as noted by SallyCJ, '**tax query**' requires a 'terms' parameter.

For example: let's say that you create two terms for your custom taxonomy - 'Type01' and "Type02' and that the slugs for those would be type01 and type02. The elements of code in your query would be like this:

```
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'downloads_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'type01', 'type02' ),
  )
```

**Third**: you need some code to actually collect the slugs. Here's my suggestion

```
// get all the terms for this custom taxonomy
        $myterms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'downloads_category',
                'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );    
        //echo "the terms are <pre>";print_r($myterms);echo "</pre>"; //DEBUG

        //create a simple array to store the terms for use in a query
        $termsarray = []; 
        // get the slugs only
        $termsarray = wp_list_pluck( $myterms, 'slug' );
        //echo "terms array is <pre>";print_r($termsarray);echo "</pre>"; //DEBUG
```

**Fourth**: you need to insert the slugs into the query. This code has been tested and works. Of course, the variable $termsarray in this code is the same variable as in the previous note.

```
// build a new query to get all the posts for the custom taxonomy
        $myargs = array(
                'post_type' => 'downloads',
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'downloads_category',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $termsarray,
                        )
                )
        );
```

**Fifth**: I suggest an alternative to using archive.php. Instead create a taxonomy file for your custom taxonomy. I created a "taxonomy-categoria-de-downloads.php" from a copy of archive.php. It works just fine and lets you format the output for your custom taxonomy without having to make the archive template more complicated.

At times like this, it's  important to have a firm grasp on which templates are called in certain situations. The [Codex Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies) is essential and "[Visualize The Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com)" is very highly recommended.

**Sixth**: In an earlier version of this answer, I outlined the files to display the custom post itself, with the terms highlighted. On refection, the question doesn't mention this at all, and I have removed it as irrelevant. If the OP would like to see it, I can easily re-post.

Comment: Actually just inserting the terms on query solved it! 'terms' => get_queried_object_id()

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I took that job again just now.

Comment: No worries. I knew it would be something simple. BTW, I do think that using a taxonomy template could be a better solution.